# MySQL - Add to sum based on if

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table, `StatementItem` which stores late fees, charges for services received, and payments for services received from a business. late fees and  charges for services received are negative values. Payments for services received are positive values.

I need to calculate the late fee for a given month.  Generally speaking, A month's late fee is calculated based on the following formula:

```
late_fee = (total_cost_of_all services that were received >= a month ago + all_payments_to_date) *1.5%
```

The problem I am having is the following:

A service is only eligible for inclusion in `total_cost_of_all services that were received >= a month ago` if it was NOT included in three months of other `late_fee` calculations.

Late fees can be detected in the table when the property `sid` === `29`.

We are to assume that any service that occurs prior to three charges where `sid === 29` has already received 3 late charges and is ineligible for inclusion in the current month's late fee calculation.

Taking all of this into consideration, is there a way I can calculate a given month's late fee using MySQL? I have the following thus far:

```
SELECT 
    c.c_id,
    (
       SELECT SUM (si_amount)
       FROM StatementItem si
       WHERE c.c_id = s.c_id 
           AND (si.si_amount < 0 AND si.si_posting_date < "2022-05-20");
    ) as total_eligible_for_late_fees,
    (
       SELECT SUM (si_amount)
       FROM StatementItem si
       WHERE c.c_id = s.c_id 
          AND (si.si_amount > 0);
    ) as all_payments_to_date,
FROM Customer c
```

Is there a good way to get `StatementItems` that do not have three late charges after them in the `StatementItem` table?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need sub-queries to do these calculations when you can use the SUM aggregate function -- I've shown an example below that does the same as your query.

You can use the SUM with CASE in complicated equations (to for example calculate the penalty due.

```
SELECT c.c_id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN si.si_amount < 0 AND si.si_posting_date < "2022-05-20" THEN si_amount ELSE 0 END) as total_eligible_for_late_fees,
       SUM(CASE WHEN si.si_amount > 0 THEN si_amount ELSE 0 END) AS all_payments_to_date
FROM Customer c
LEFT JOIN StatementItem si ON c.c_id = s.c_id
GROUP BY c.c_id
```

Comment: How would I check that the statement item does not have three late fees after it belonging to the customer in the table though?

In other words, if a statement item has already been included in the 3 other late fee charges, we cannot include it in `total_eligible_for_late_fees`

Comment: Each statement item has a primary key, `si_id`, that auto increments

Comment: @J.spenc -- do you have a table that lists what late fee charges have been made attributed to this statement?  If you don't have it in the data model there no way to check it.  If it is in the data model tell where in the model it is located.

Comment: no they are wanting me to determine if something is eligible to be added into the sum that is `total_eligible_for_late_fees`, based on if 3 late fees occur for the customer after the charge. If 3 late fees occur for the customer after the charge we don't include the charge

Comment: @J.spenc -- I don't have access to your database.  In what table and what column would I query to find "if 3 late fees occur for the customer after the charge"  Is there a table where the late fees are stored?  is there a table where the charge is stored?  I don't know any of these things -- you have to tell me.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not communicating well. The late fees are stored in the table StatementItem. The charges for Services are also stored in StatementItem.

Comment: A row in the StatementItem table is a late fee if it has `si_id` === "29".

Comment: If a Statement Item's si_id!== "29" and occurs prior to 3 Statement items where si_id === "29", it is not allowed in the  `total_eligible_for_late_fees`